# Bochs "read beyond limit"

Tags: assembly, i386, bochs

I am trying to boot a custom kernel in Bochs. However, when I try to run it, Bochs generates hundreds of thousands of output lines to my terminal over the span of a few seconds. All of them contain the same message:

```
00017895741e[CPU0  ] read_virtual_checks(): read beyond limit
```

I am using an image created by `dd if=/dev/disk3s1 of=Boot.img`, where disk3s1 is the raw device used by my Mac’s DMG mounting driver. (This image boots just fine under QEMU, but due to incompatibilities between my kernel and QEMU, I have to use Bochs now.) Here is the contents of my bochsrc file:

```
megs: 1024
ata0-master: type=disk, path=Boot.img, mode=flat, cylinders=0
boot: disk
```

I have tracked the cause of the issue down to [these assembly instructions](https://gist.github.com/wjk/d277b47d94049e656b3c#file-boot2-s-L8499-L8500). What is happening, is that the CPU has just been switched into real mode so it can make a BIOS interrupt. Before the switch, the registers to be used in a BIOS interrupt have been saved into the memory locations indicated by the symbols `new_eax`, `new_edx`, and `new_es`. Once in real mode, the program re-loads the registers from the appropriate memory locations. The linear address of the memory location to be read from is `0x000200c8`. However, because we are in real mode, we must use segment-relative addressing — in this case, `ds:0x000100c8`. However, the `ds` register has the value `0x2000`. When combined with the offset, we get linear address `0x000300c8`, which is not valid. The “read beyond limit” message is Bochs complaining that the address is invalid. The reason it is printed so many times is because the invalid instruction is being run again and again in an infinite loop.

Again, I would like to stress that this *exact same code* runs *just fine* in QEMU. I cannot fathom why this would be.

Here is [the complete disassembly of my running boot loader](https://gist.github.com/wjk/d277b47d94049e656b3c#file-boot2-s) and [the C source code for my boot loader](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/booter) (see the `boot2` and `libsaio` subdirectories in particular), if it is helpful.

Comment: The first part of the line is likely not a timestamp, but the address of the read that caused the fault.

Comment: @hobbs : It is the number of simulated timer ticks. The `e` on the end just means it is an entry representing an error message

Comment: Dumb question but when you go back to real mode why are you using _DS_ of 0x2000. I haven't looked at your code, but why not _DS_ 0x1000? Or if you need to use _DS_ with a value of 0x2000) why not subtract 0x10000 from 0x000100c8 and use that as the offset which would be 0x2000:0x00c8 = 0x200c8.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having this same issue with my bootloader - it works in qemu and on an actual computer but in Bochs it gets the error you described. via @WilliamHilton

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having this same issue with my bootloader - it works in qemu and on an actual computer but in Bochs it gets the error you described.

Comment: @WilliamHilton : Create a new question and post your code inside the question so we can look at it.